# Converting EPOC datetime to PST in python/ruby

Tags: python, ruby, datetime, activesupport

I get an input as this: `1410627645`.

I need to convert this to PST. It should be around 2014/09/13-10:00:00. How do I convert it in python/ruby. How do I recognize the time zone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Time.at(1410627645).to_datetime.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
#=> Sat, 13 Sep 2014 10:00:45 PDT -07:00
```

or simply

```
Time.at(1410627645).in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
#=> Sat, 13 Sep 2014 10:00:45 PDT -07:00
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Time.at(1410627645).to_datetime
#=> Sat, 13 Sep 2014 19:00:45 +0200
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `datetime`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1410627645)
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 13, 22, 30, 45)
```

now you can sore this in some variable called `my_time`:

```
>>> my_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1410627645)
>>> "{}/{}/{}-{}:{}:{}".format(my_time.year,my_time.month,my_time.day,my_time.hour,my_time.minute,my_time.second)
'2014/9/13-22:30:45'
```

you can identify time zone by `time.gmtime`:

```
>>> time.gmtime(1410627645)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2014, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=13, tm_hour=17, tm_min=0, tm_sec=45, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=256, tm_isdst=0)
```

Comment: you could use `my_time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S')` instead of the `'...'.format(...)` call. Don't use `fromtimestamp()` method without specifying a timezone otherwise it returns naive datetime objects that are ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you can also use strftime like this:

```
DateTime.strftime("1410627645",'%s')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input is "seconds since Epoch" (POSIX time) then you could use [`datetime.fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) method to convert it to the broken-down time in Python.

To get time in UTC timezone:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> utc_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(1410627645, timezone.utc)
>>> utc_dt
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 13, 17, 0, 45, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> print(utc_dt)
2014-09-13 17:00:45+00:00
```

To get time in your local timezone:

```
>>> local_dt = utc_dt.astimezone()
>>> local_dt
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 13, 10, 0, 45,
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200), 'PDT'))
>>> print(local_dt)
2014-09-13 10:00:45-07:00
```

To get time in the specified timezone:

```
>>> import pytz
>>> dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(1410627645, pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 13, 10, 0, 45, 
        tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PDT-1 day, 17:00:00 DST>)
>>> print(dt)
2014-09-13 10:00:45-07:00
```